# viewModelProvider owner advice?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

To me, the information about ViewModelProvider lack some details and as usual I'm turning to StackOverflow to straighten the question marks.

In particular, I have one activity consisting of a couple of fragments, all of which are presenting the same data in different ways. What are the benefits and drawbacks with using the activity as the owner when instantiating the ViewModelProvider, vs using the fragments?

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, the ViewModel class is lifecycle aware. this means the ViewModel class you defined is going to be managed according to the lifecycle of the activity/fragment.

Same like Observers, it takes lifecycleOwner as a parameter. This means the observer will be alive all the time the fragment/activity is alive. If it entered OnStop, you don't have to stop observing manually, as its lifecyleOwner is the activity/fragment.

**Secondly**, For the difference between using activity as a lifecycleOwner over fragment, is the ViewModel instance will keep-alive more than defining it inside the fragment. As Activity holds the fragments. One fragment could enter onDetach(), so we guarantee that the instance of this ViewModel inside the fragment is killed. But if we define it within an activity, the life of activity is more longer.

Thirdly, I think since your case is the same data, and just the view changes in fragments, I suggest to use **SharedViewModel**, check [this article](https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments) for more details.

Hope all things are clear.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the tip. SharedViewModel is an interesting concept. It breaks the more common use case of the ViewModel being the jam between a UI and a repository, but it still presents a nice solution to a common problem. It is not applicable in my case, as I don't really have a master-detail relationship between the fragments. My use case is about presenting same data in different ways.